# EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory 3.0 exception with Eager Loading

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, in-memory-database

I am using EntityFrameworkCore and EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory 3.0.0-preview8.x for ASP.NET Core 3.0. When using Eager Loading, including navigation properties is working fine. But when it comes to unit testing with the EntiyFrameworkCore.InMemory database, the Include-Method throws an exception.

Code:

```
 public async Task<ModuleBinding> GetAsync(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            using (AppContext context = this.factory.Create())
            {
                // Return the ModuleBinding
                return await context.ModuleBinding
                           .Include(x => x.PostModule)
                           .Include(x => x.PreModule)
                           .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id)
                           .ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error($"Failed to get entity {nameof(ModuleBinding)} with id {id}.", e);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

So this works fine when using it in my application.

Test:

```
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        // Setup the in-memory database context
        DbContextOptions<AppContext> options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).Options;
        this.context = new AppContext(options);

        // Setup the factory to create an in-memory database
        var factory = A.Fake<IAppContextFactory>();
        A.CallTo(() => factory.Create()).Returns(this.context);

        // Create repository with in-memory database.
        this.repository = new ModuleBindingRepository(factory);
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task GetShouldReturnEntity()
    {
        // Arrange
        int id = this.binding1.Id;

        // Act
        ModuleBinding result = await this.repository.GetAsync(id).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.AreEqual(result, this.binding1);
    }
```

The test works also fine, as long as I remove the Includes in my GetAsync-Method. But with them, the test throws the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Operation is not valid due to the
>   current state of the object.

Do you know if this is a bug in the preview version of the EntityFrameworkCore. InMemory NuGet-Package and if there are any open threads, yet? Or did I probably do something wrong?

Comment: Worth trying latest Preview9 (or even daily builds)

Comment: That did the trick for me, thanks!